# Python Regex - remove words containing ":" from file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-negation

I have code that will remove a string from a file if the string contains `:` at the **start** of the string.

```
with open("test1.txt") as the_file:
    for each_line in the_file:
        each_line = " ".join(filter(lambda x:x[0]!=':', each_line.split()))
        print(each_line)
```

What is the correct expression to remove the string if it contains `:` **anywhere** in the string?

For example if the file contains `:raining, raining:, rai:ning`, It will only remove `:raining`. I want to remove all of these words from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help. Removes all string which has `":"` in it.

```
a = ":raining, raining:, rai:ning  aaaaaaa"
def removeStr(val):
    if ":" not in val:
        return val

each_line = " ".join(filter(removeStr, a.split()))
print each_line
```

**Output:**

```
aaaaaaa
```

Comment: Thank you, much quicker than regex.

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if ':' in line:
            # Remove
        else:
            # Keep
```

Comment: This is correct, nice. You can use `continue` in the `if`, and then you don't need the else.

Comment: @kabanus Yes, agree with you. I didn't write the logic of removing lines, but gave just the concept of how it can be done.

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks! Edited.